# Drawing a perfect horizontal line at a specific position with a fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, shader

is it possible to draw a perfect horizontal line of a single pixel height at any chosen position on the vertical axis with a fragment shader applied to a screen aligned quad?

I have found many solutions with smoothstep or more complex functions but i am looking for an elegant and fast way of doing this.

A solution i have made is by using an exponential function and making it steeper but it have many shortcomings that i don't want (the line is not really one pixel height due to the exponential function and it is rather tricky to get one right), here is the GLSL code :

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;

    // a centered horizontal line
    float v = pow(uv.y - 0.5, 2.);

    // make it steeper
    v *= 100000.;

    // make it white on a black background
    v = clamp(1. - v, 0., 1.);

    fragColor = vec4(v);
}
```

Here is the shadertoy code which execute this: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Ms2cWh

What i would like :

- a perfect horizontal line drawn to a specific Y position in pixels units or normalized
- its intensity limited to [0, 1] range without clamping
- a fast way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to:

> draw a perfect horizontal line of a single pixel height at any chosen
>   position on the vertical axis with a fragment shader applied to a
>   screen aligned quad

, then maybe:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    int iPosition = 250; // the y coord in pixels
    int iThickness = 10; // the thickness in pixels

    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;

    float v = float( iPosition ) / iResolution.y;
    float vHalfHeight = ( float( iThickness ) / ( iResolution.y ) ) / 2.;

    if ( uv.y > v - vHalfHeight && uv.y < v + vHalfHeight )
        fragColor = vec4(1.,1.,1.,1.); // or whatever color
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution is perfect except for the performances, i knew that solution somewhat but the branching is kind of a no go, i guess there is a way to optimize this by removing the conditional.

Comment: So, i don't know the computational cost of the `step` function but i removed the branching by doing `v = step(uv.y, v + vHalfHeight) - step(uv.y, v - vHalfHeight);`

Comment: Nice work! Do you know of any simple tool used to measure the execution time of a shader? Probably could loop it a few thousand times between high resolution clock ticks! :)

Comment: Nop but i would be interested to know how it is possible as well :)

Comment: iq and abje on ShaderToy posted a very elegant solution (with branching) `fragColor = vec4(fragCoord.y+0.5 == iPosition)` i wonder if that is the fastest?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dScWW) is a neat solution without branching. I don't know if it is really faster than with branching though.

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;

    float py = iMouse.y/iResolution.y;

    float hh = 1./iResolution.y;

    // can also be replace with step(0., hh-abs(uv.y-py))
    float v = sign(hh-abs(uv.y-py));

    fragColor = vec4(v);
}
```

Comment: Zabidon on ShaderToy posted what appear a better solution with `v = step(abs(fragCoord.y - py), 1.);` thank to him!

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was answered properly before me, but in case someone is looking for a way to render a textured line in a pixel perfect way I wrote an [article](https://www.quizcanners.com/single-post/2018/10/03/Pixel-Perfect-Shader) with some examples.

It's about pixel perfect UI in general, but using it for a line is just a matter of clamping/repeating texture sampling. Also I'm using Unity, but there is no reason the method would be exclusive to it.